# Вызов emit в nodejs, через отправку CURL на стороне PHP

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io, express

На PHP есть сервис который меняет статусы у заказа. При смене статуса в сервис NODEJS уходит POST запрос через CURL.
Нода принимает его нормально, запрос уходит на роутинг нодовского экспресса

```
router.post('/status/set-archive', function (req, res, next) {
    setStatus(req, res);
    res.end();
});
```

после того как данный сервис был вызван, мне необходимо отправить emit нужному клиенту. Сами сокеты я инициализировал в глобальную переменную

```
global.ioS = io;
```

А дальше уже в setStatus я пытаюсь его отправить.

```
global.ioS.sockets.in({user: '10'}).emit('notify-msg')
```

Но данные на клиент так и не приходят, хотя объект в **console.log(global.ioS.sockets)** существует. 
Возможно я инициализацию делаю не правильно или что то другое, подскажите кто сталкивался с подобным решением.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);
const room = 10; // вместо объекта номер комнаты    

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('yourEvent', () => {
    io.to(room).emit('notify-msg');  
  });
});
```

У меня в похожей ситуации отработало, надеюсь и Вам поможет.

Comment: Основная проблема была не на стороне node js, а на стороне php,  у меня отправка заработала когда я в CURL добавил параметр для заголовка  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));`